# Tell proftp to allow connections only to the users that have permissions in PostgreSQL

Tags: ftp, database, postgresql, proftpd

I'm trying to set up an ftp server for the first time (under `Debian Squeeze`) and after searching through Google, I decided to use `proftp`.

**NOTE:** I have a `PostgreSQL` server running in the same machine where the ftp will be.

I now have a question about *virtual users*.
Looking at some howto's, I think that the best way to set up the ftp is to use virtual users, but all those howto's I found create a new database to store the login/password information, whereas I want `proftpd` to allow connection only to those users who have rights in `PostgreSQL`. I mean, **only to those users that are listed when doing this**:

```
# su - postgres
$ psql
$ \du
```

I have modified the `sql.conf` file accordingly to my needs, but I'm not sure what to do with the last sections:

```
<IfModule mod_sql.c>
SQLBackend  postgres
SQLEngine on
SQLAuthenticate on
SQLAuthTypes Backend Crypt

#SQLConnectInfo proftpd@sql.example.com proftpd_user proftpd_password

#
# Describes both users/groups tables
#
#SQLUserInfo users userid passwd uid gid homedir shell
#SQLGroupInfo groups groupname gid members
#
```

And is the `groups` table required?

I'm asking before doing something funny with the server and mess it up.

**EDIT 1:** This is what `\du` prints. The column tags may be wrong as I'm translating directly from Spanish and I don't know how the chart is displayed in English. So sorry about that.

So, the users I would like to be able to connect to the ftp are: *chair_1*, *chair_2*, *wall_1* and *myuser*.

```
                  Role List
 Role name     |      Attributes     | Member of 
---------------+---------------------+------------
 chair         | Can't connect       | {}
 chair_1       |                     | {chair}
 chair_2       |                     | {chair}
 wall          | Can't connect       | {}
 wall_1        |                     | {wall}
 myuser        | Superuser           | {}
               : Create role             
               : Create BD              
 postgres      | Superuser           | {}
               : Create role             
               : Create BD
```

Comment: You mean checking permissions on postgresql in addition to providing your own `users` table/view or instead of it? In the latter case how do you get the fields like uid,gid,homedir...?

Comment: @DanielVérité What I want is something like: 1-I connect to the ftp with my login/pass. 2-If my login is listed in the `Role name` column of `\du` output, let me in. If not, refuse the connection. I think this would be the `instead of it` case. In that case, is it possible to have all the `Role names` have the same gid and homedir?