# Can't connect to proftpd from outside the virtual machine

Tags: windows-7, virtual-machines, virtualbox, ubuntu-10.04, ftp

This is related to a [previous question](https://serverfault.com/questions/567709/tell-proftp-to-allow-connections-only-to-the-users-that-have-permissions-in-post). I have a machine with `Windows 7` acting as a server and it hosts several virtual machines. One of them, a `Debian Squeezy` is acting as a `PostgreSQL` server and I want to add a ftp server in that same virtual machine (**Note:** the network adaptor is NAT).

Since I can't figure out how to connect `PostgreSQL` and `proftpd`, I searched for other ways of setting up the ftp server and found [this tutorial in ubuntuforums](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=79588).

I followed all the steps in the **SECURE WAY** (in my vm, the port, the new user, etc. are exactly the same as those in the howto) and got the ftp server running. I launched `FileZilla` from inside the virtual machine and connected to the ftp with the new user's credentials.

Now, I tried to do it from the my pc, but received an error: `"ECONNREFUSED - Connection refused by server"`.

In the `VirtualBox Administrator` I modified the networking settings of the `Debian VM` and forwarded the ports:

*HOST IP:* The ip of the machine where is located the vm.
*GUEST IP:* The vm's internal ip.

```
Protocol        HOST IP          HOST PORT   GUEST IP     GUEST PORT
----------------------------------------------------------------------
TCP             193.147.83.213   1080        10.0.2.15    1080
TCP             193.147.83.213   1980        10.0.2.15    21
TCP             193.147.83.213   21          10.0.2.15    1980
```

Since I can connect to the ftp from inside the vm, I guess this has something to do with the comunnication between the virtual machine and my pc.

Do you have any ideas?

Do I need to forward more ports?
Might the Windows firewall and/or iptables be interfering too?

**EDIT 1:** As requested by @DavidHoude, I updated the question with the outputs of *iptables -L* and *netstat -a | grep LISTEN*. I must say that the configuration of `iptables` is the same I found in the vm, I didn't change a bit.

*iptbles -l*

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination
```

*netstat -a | grep LISTEN*

```
tcp        0      0 localhost:ipp           *:*                     LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 localhost:ipp           [::]:*                  LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 [::]:1980               [::]:*                  LISTEN     
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     4563     /tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     6328     /tmp/ssh-EFteMx1139/agent.1139
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     6370     /tmp/.ICE-unix/1139
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     6390     /tmp/orbit-a/linc-4d1-0-262fd8c7bf7a5
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     6635     /tmp/orbit-a/linc-473-0-7e706cd3d32d5
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     6761     /tmp/keyring-GWAtQJ/pkcs11
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9031     /tmp/orbit-a/linc-5ac-0-614ad9120e41
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9095     /tmp/orbit-a/linc-5b2-0-247b523c8e0b
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     5971     /tmp/keyring-GWAtQJ/control
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     6767     /tmp/keyring-GWAtQJ/ssh
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     6782     /tmp/orbit-a/linc-4d8-0-76e5819d5f759
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     4377     /var/run/cups/cups.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     3865     /var/run/acpid.socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     7501     /tmp/orbit-a/linc-4e7-0-bece60f85ca
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     7334     /tmp/.esd-1000/socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     7337     /home/a/.pulse/7624943c4bf56849714f10145193c093-runtime/native
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     7443     /tmp/orbit-a/linc-4fd-0-c6f9eb936d6
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     7516     /tmp/orbit-a/linc-4e5-0-1fec0a3016600
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     7579     /tmp/orbit-a/linc-4f7-0-32a7a613dbfdf
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     7603     /tmp/orbit-a/linc-4fc-0-42c73bd03fa7f
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     7682     /tmp/orbit-a/linc-4e1-0-273dbd256f377
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     7938     /tmp/orbit-a/linc-55a-0-27cffa947264b
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8030     /tmp/orbit-a/linc-55b-0-27dc07accde53
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8326     /tmp/orbit-a/linc-570-0-2805454d11289
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8333     /tmp/orbit-a/linc-566-0-16563300170a4
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8335     /tmp/orbit-a/linc-567-0-2da4230a172b8
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     4395     /var/run/proftpd/proftpd.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8338     /tmp/orbit-a/linc-573-0-4a085d80176ac
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8351     /tmp/orbit-a/linc-572-0-4206a1b81f802
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8414     /tmp/orbit-a/linc-571-0-6c1f35c65e634
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8443     /tmp/orbit-a/linc-4df-0-8dc2a346fe5f
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8554     /tmp/orbit-a/linc-581-0-797b154e59d83
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     8587     /tmp/orbit-a/linc-584-0-1c5fd995d9a9a
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     9275     /tmp/orbit-a/linc-5cf-0-5f48faccd63f5
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     4403     /var/run/proftpd/proftpd.sock
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     2334     @/com/ubuntu/upstart
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     5450     @/var/run/hald/dbus-NI6LFIbNzq
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     5455     @/var/run/hald/dbus-87f9eAAnp3
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     3412     /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     4562     @/tmp/.X11-unix/X0
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     6369     @/tmp/.ICE-unix/1139
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     3489     /var/run/avahi-daemon/socket
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     4781     @/tmp/gdm-session-UHdjqzQA
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     4639     @/tmp/gdm-greeter-mvMQrpxI
unix  2      [ ACC ]     STREAM     LISTENING     6341     @/tmp/dbus-KUrgd752tT
```

**EDIT 2:** After @dusan.bajic suggestion, I added `MasqueradeAddress 193.147.83.213` to the `proftpd.conf` file.

Now FileZilla outputs this:

```
Estado: Connecting to 193.147.83.213:1980...
Estado: Connection established, waiting for welcoming message...
Error:  Couldn't connect to server
```

I might say that I'm using FileZilla from my Windows machine like this:

```
Server: 193.147.83.213
User: sauron
Port: 1980
```

**EDIT 2:**

@dusan.bajic got a point. I disabled the firewall and this happended:

```
Resposne:   331 Password required for sauron
Command:    PASS ******
Response:   230 welcome !!!
Command:    SYST
Response:   215 UNIX Type: L8
Command:    FEAT
Response:   211-Features:
Response:    MDTM
Response:    MFMT
Response:    UTF8
Response:    LANG en-US.utf8*
Response:    MFF modify;UNIX.group;UNIX.mode;
Response:    MLST modify*;perm*;size*;type*;unique*;UNIX.group*;UNIX.mode*;UNIX.owner*;
Response:    REST STREAM
Response:    SIZE
Response:   211 End
Command:    OPTS UTF8 ON
Response:   200 UTF8 set to on
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is the current directory
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (193,147,83,213,152,251).
Command:    MLSD
Error:  Connection timeout exceeded
Error:  Error retrieving directory listing
```

So it seems that it connected but when entering in `passive mode` (by the way, what are the numbers in parentheses? Ports? )

Comment: The last line in your network settings should be TCP             193.147.83.213   21          10.0.2.15    1980

Comment: @dusan.bajic And it is 1980! It's a typo. I'll correct it now.

Comment: What is the output of iptables -L and netstat -a | grep LISTEN? Also why use ftp, SCP is recommended these days and most people already have SSH running.

Comment: @DavidHoude I updated my question with the info you requested. As for why use FTP, it's a job requirement. But if I can get this ftp thing to run, I'll try with SCP too.

Comment: Try adding MasqueradeAddress 193.147.83.213 to your proftpd.conf

Comment: @dusan.bajic Done! See my update in the question

Comment: I never had any luck with NAT. I prefer Bridged or Internal.

Comment: Seems that port 1980 listen on ipv6 only...

Comment: @user2196728 Oh! And is way to make it listen on ipv4? Or it's better to try with another port?

Comment: try `UseIPv6 off` in `proftpd.conf`

Comment: @user2196728 I added it but I get the same error message("waiting for welcoming message"...)

Comment: Make sure firewall is off (at least while testing) on your client machine.

Comment: @dusan.bajic Done! I disabled the firewall entirely. It connected but entered pasive mode and disconnected. I updated my question with the new info.

Comment: Using pasive mode will require some additional settings both on NAT and proftpd. I suggest you configure your ftp client to use active mode.

Comment: Also: first four numbers in parentheses are server IP address, the other two are port number advertized by server (calculated as 152*256+251 giving port 39163), which is why connection breaks at that pooint as you don't have that port forwarded on your NAT.

Comment: @dusan.bajic Thanks! I'll re-configure the client and post the update!

Comment: any luck......?

Comment: @dusan.bajic Woah, I forgot about this, sorry. I had (still have) to do some priority work and left this behind. One co-worker found a temporary solution until the workload diminishes, so once I'm free I'll return to this problem. Sorry for any inconveniences!